# is there a method to compare value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

i have arrayObject :

```
[{"text": "blabla" , "label": 0.34}, {"text":"lablab", "label":0.12},{"text":"ababab", "label":0.89}]
```

i want to display in javascript only data with "label" > 0.3
i want to have in output :

```
[{"text": "blabla" , "label": 0.34},{"text":"ababab", "label":0.89}]
```

Comment: Use `Array.map()` and return only the objects that match your criteria to the resulting array.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - you mean, `filter` (not `map`), I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple `Array.filter`. I deconstructed the object and compared the label to the target value.

```js
console.log([{"text": "blabla" , "label": 0.34}, {"text":"lablab", "label":0.12},{"text":"ababab", "label":0.89}].filter(({text, label}) => label > 0.3))
```

Comment: but i have this errror TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a higher order function called `filter` to solve this issue.

Follow this link to guide you: [Higher Order Functions: How to use filter, map and reduce](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/higher-order-functions-in-javascript-d9101f9cf528/)

Basically, the syntax is `array.filter(key => key.label > 0.3)`

Comment: It would be `key.label > 0.3`, not `key.label > 3.0`

Comment: Ops, sorry! I fixed!